# Is there a way to have a reference to a group of views?

Tags: swiftui

I have something like this:

```
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      VStack {
        MyView1()
        MyView2()
        MyView3()
      }
      MyToolbar()
    }
  }
```

At one point I will need to grab a screenshot of the `VStack`, as it is seen on the screen.

I am using a `view` extension like this:

```
extension View {
  func snapshot() -> UIImage {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)

    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
    let view = controller.view

    view?.bounds = rect // CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
    view?.backgroundColor = .clear

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: screenSize)

    return renderer.image { _ in
      view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
  }
}
```

That will grab the whole hierarchy of what is inside the referenced view, like:

```
let snapshot = vstack.snapshot()
```

but for that to work I need a reference to that `VStack`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Check this out: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-convert-a-swiftui-view-to-an-image

Comment: I know how to create a snapshot, my question is about something else.

Comment: Yeah but check out how he defined `var textView: some View {`. You can do that for your `VStack` too: `var vStack: some View { MyView1() ... }`

Comment: Working fine. Please convert this comment of yours into an answer, so I can accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that is to create your `VStack` view content as a computed property.

#### 1. Create the view as a computed property:

```
private var stackContent: some View {
    VStack {
      MyView1()
      MyView2()
      MyView3()
    }
}
```

#### 2. Use your created view as you wish:

```
var body: some View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            stackContent
            MyToolbar()
        }
      }

}
```

#### 3. Access it easily simply by the name you gave it:

```
let snapshot = stackContent.snapshot()
```

Comment: Btw `VSStackContent` should probably be lowercased, unless is there a different convention for SwiftUI views?

Comment: @aheze I'd still go lowercase too (it's a property, not a struct)

Comment: @aheze, @George I agree, that should definitely be `camel-case` in this context.

Comment: SIMPLY BRILLIANT! THANKS